# Access control of objects in Julia Web Platform

Tags: api, julia

We are creating a online platform and exposing an Julia API via a embedded code-editor. The user can access the API and run some analysis on our web-app. I have a question related to controlling access to the API and objects.

The API right now contains a database handle and other objects that are exposed to the user and can be used to hack the internal system.

Below is the current architecture:

UserProgram.jl

```
function doanalysis()
   data = getdata()
   # some analysis on data
end
```

InternalProgram.jl

```
const client = MongoClient()
const collection = MongoCollection(client,"dbname","collectionName")

function getdata()
   data = #some function to get data from collection
   return data
end

#after parsing the user program 
doanalysis()
```

To run the user analysis, we pass user program as a command-line argument (using ArgParse module) and run the internal program as follows

```
$ julia InternalProgram.jl --file Userprogram.jl
```

With this architecture, user potentially gets access to "client" and "collection" and can modify internal databases.

Is there a better way to solve this problem without exposing the objects?

I hope someone has an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be exposing yourself to multiple types of vulnerabilities - as the general rule, executing user inputed code is a VERY BAD IDEA.

1/ like you said, you'll potentially allow users to execute random code against your database.

2/ your users will have access to all the power of Julia to do things on your server (download files they can later execute for example, access other servers and services on the server [MySQL, email, etc]). Depending on the level of access of the Julia process, think unauthorized access to your file system, installing key loggers, running spam servers, etc.

3/ will be able to use Julia packages and get you into a lot of trouble - like for example add/use the Requests.jl package and execute DoS attacks on other servers.

If you really want to go this way, I recommend that:

A/ set proper (minimal) permissions for the MongoDB user configured to be used in the app (ex: http://blog.mlab.com/2016/07/mongodb-tips-tricks-collection-level-access-control/)

B/ execute each user's code into a separate sandbox / container that only exposes the minimum necessary software

C/ have your containers running on a managed platform where tooling exists (firewalls) to monitor incoming and outgoing traffic (for example to block spam or DoS attacks)

In order to achieve B/ and C/ my recommendation is to use JuliaBox. I haven't used it myself, but seems to be exactly what you need: https://github.com/JuliaCloud/JuliaBox

Once you get that running, you can also use https://github.com/JuliaWeb/JuliaWebAPI.jl

Comment: A lot of it makes sense. Is it possible to integrate JuliaBox in your application or is it a independent service? I guess it's latter.  Any pointers on how to achieve B independently of JuliaBox? Thanks!!